# Multiple result set from SQL Via LiNQ

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a stored procedure as

> pr___GetArchiveData
>
> Select * from TABLE1
>
> SELECT * FROM TABLE2
>
> SELECT * FROM TABLE 3

I want to get this result set into a dataset. Or access the values of three select queries!!
I have a DBML file in which when i drag and drop the stored procedure generates a code as follows:-

```
global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.pr___GetArchiveData")]
    public ISingleResult<pr___GetArchiveDataResult> pr___GetArchiveData([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="UniqueIdentifier")] System.Nullable<System.Guid> projectID)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), projectID);
        return ((ISingleResult<pr__Project_pr___GetArchiveData>)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
```

In the code MVC3 Architecture + LINQ i have written a code to get the result set as follows :-

```
using (HBDataContext hb = new HBDataContext())
                {
                    System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();

                    String connString = connString;

                    var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString);
                    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "pr__GetArchiveData";
                    cmd.Connection.Open();

                    var mReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
                    //var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    //using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader mReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    //{
                    //  while (mReader.Read())
                    //{
                    // mReader.Read();

                    var tbl1 = hb.Translate<tbl1 >(mReader).ToList();

                  //  mReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    mReader.NextResult();
                    var tbl2 = hb.Translate<tbl2 >(mReader).ToList();

                    mReader.NextResult();
                    var tbl3 = hb.Translate<tbl3>(mReader).ToList();

                  
                    // }
                    // }
                }
```

But while running it throws error as -

> "Invalid attempt to call NextResult when reader is closed."

I am not sure where i am wrong!!

I have tried using it as while

> (mReader.Read())

Kindly suggest!!!!

Comment: Have you looked into using your SP function pr___GetArchiveData and just returning an ISingleResult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In .dbml file for the stored procedure  the code will be like

   `[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.pr__Home_GetArchiveData")]
           public ISingleResult<pr__Home_GetArchiveData> pr__Home_GetArchiveData([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="AlbumID", DbType="UniqueIdentifier")] System.Nullable<System.Guid> albumID)
           {
               IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), albumID);
               return ((ISingleResult<pr__Album_GetAlbumsFilesResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
       }`
2. Replace it with IMultipleResult as below `

   [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name = "dbo.pr__Home_GetArchiveData")]
           [ResultType(typeof(tbl1))]
           [ResultType(typeof(tbl2))]
           [ResultType(typeof(tbl3))]
           [ResultType(typeof(tbl4))]
           public IMultipleResults pr__Home_GetArchiveData([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "HOMEID", DbType = "UniqueIdentifier")] System.Nullable hOMEID)
           {
               IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), hOMEID);
               return ((IMultipleResults)result.ReturnValue);
           }

in the code .

```
 using (HBDataContext hb = new HBDataContext())
                {
                    using (System.Data.Linq.IMultipleResults _results = hb.pr__Home_GetArchiveData(model.HomeID))
                    {
                        List<tbl1> _tbl1= _results.GetResult<tbl1>().ToList();
                        List<tbl2> _tbl2= _results.GetResult<tbl2>().ToList();
                        List<tbl3> _tbl3= _results.GetResult<tbl3>().ToList();
                        List<tbl4> _tbl4= _results.GetResult<tbl4>().ToList();}}
```

You will get the values of the Select queries from theStoredProcedure ...

Answer (score 1):

The code gen for `ISingleResult` won't provide multiple result sets

Try adding your own `IMultipleResults` wrapper - see the tutorial in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dditweb/archive/2008/05/06/linq-to-sql-and-multiple-result-sets-in-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: Thank you Stuart. It worked. Just a little work around with your suggested link :)